# Faceting with solr php client

Tags: php, solr

I am trying to get the faceting results and I don't know how. there are no documentation for `solr-php-client`. In this example, `print_r( $response->getRawResponse() )` does not include faceting. I am not sure weather faceting is not successfully requested or it is a matter of accessing the faceting data in the responce. Please also help me if there is any documentation available online for `solr-php-client`.

An other question is how to declare "user/password" if solr is protected when initiating the instance of `solr-php-client`

```
require_once( 'solr-php-client/Apache/Solr/Service.php' );


$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service( 'localhost', '8983', '/solr/products' );

if ( ! $solr->ping() ) {
   echo 'Solr service not responding.';
   exit;
}


$offset = 0;
$limit = 10;


$queries = array(
  'name:iphone'
);
$additionalParameters = array(
  'facet' => 'true',
  'facet.field' => array(
     'category'
  )
);

foreach ( $queries as $query ) {
$response = $solr->search( $query, $offset, $limit );

if ( $response->getHttpStatus() == 200 ) {
   print_r( $response->getRawResponse() );

  if ( $response->response->numFound > 0 ) {
    echo "$query <br />";

    foreach ( $response->response->docs as $doc ) {
      echo "$doc->id $doc->name <br />";
    }

    echo '<br />';
  }else{
    echo "zero results";
  }
}
else {
  echo $response->getHttpStatusMessage();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed to add `$additionalParameters` to the `search` arguements;

```
 $response = $solr->search( $query, $offset, $limit,$additionalParameters );
```